# Headless without javascript

Tags: javascript, headless, laravel-framework

Recently I was thinking about going headless in order to improve performance of a magento store and also at least in theory faster front-end development and faster deployment.

But going headless by using a JS framework ruins SEO of the store which is major issue. So what about using magento's REST API with another php application using laravel for example or symfony or whatever as the frontend?

Would it considered overkill? Or slow in that matter?  Any opinions??

Thank you!

Comment: It would be a lot of work

Comment: In what sense? Can you elaborate your thoughts on that?? In what areas would you believe it's going to need more work than it should?? Thanks!!

Comment: What you have described is something similar to a PWA. But there are teams (and you would need a team) already working on them. https://docs.vuestorefront.io/guide/installation/magento.html plus magento's own https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/ . But I assume you have looked at these already (Are these the ones with issues with SEO you described?) and are instead looking at alternatives. Maybe you should look beyond magento. Look at Sylius for example.